# CKEditor Hide button without hide the function

Tags: function, button, ckeditor, hide

I'm using `CKEditor` and I would like to `hide a button` in keeping the functions. In other words I would like to hide the Image button while keeping all existing images displayed in
my page

I tried to use the `config.js` file:

```
- config.removeButtons = 'Image'; 
- config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,image';
```

But all existing images in my html page disapeared.
I have the same trouble withe the Table button.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This helps community members of stackoverflow help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
.cke_button__image, .cke_button__table {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wizard that's it !